# Problems using Tensorflow in PyCharm-keep getting ImportError

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pycharm, importerror

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Since you have in the log

> Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib

I would say you've installed TF with CUDA support but didn't install CUDA libraries properly. Try to install TF CPU only.